# Add mAP metric for train

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard

I'm using tensorflow object detection API and I'll like to see in tesnorboard the mAP metric also for the train.
is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: One way to do it would be to have a config file meant to evaluate on the training data, and running an evaluation job that uses your data. I also wanted to do it the right way (just get the metrics directly during training), but didn't manage to do so...

Comment: Thanks for the share